# Python - what is "" mean

Tags: python, authentication, passwords

I am using Python and figuring how to write a program that asks for a UN and password. I am using a tutorial for "while loops".

For the Command and Input1 and Input2, why are do they show the variable to equal ""

They show:

```
name = raw_input("What is your UserName: ") 
password = raw_input("What is your Password: ") 
print "To lock your computer type lock."    
command = ""
input1 = ""
input2 = ""
while command != "lock":
    command = raw_input("What is your command: ") 
while input1 != name:
    input1 = raw_input("What is your username: ")
```

￼￼￼￼

Answer (score 1):

It just means that they are declaring two strings `input1` and `input2` and making sure they are empty strings before accepting user inputs.

Comment: It is also like the JavaScript way of saying                                   `var input1; var input2;`

Answer (score 0):

Using `command=""` will create a variable called command that is an empty string. This is often used so you can clear the variable and use it again.

For example:

```
>>> command = "hello world"
>>> print command
hello world
>>> command = ""
>>> print command

>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

They are defining the variables before use them, otherwise you gonna have an error that command is not defined and your program will fail.